# lxml XSLT removes CDATA while processing XML

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

Handling CDATA with lxml involves making parser with suitable declaration, but how about XSLT?
For example:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree = etree.parse('sample_with_cdata.xml', parser)
transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse('dupe.xsl'))
xml_out = transform(tree)
xml_out.write('processed.xml')
```

If I process xml file with CDATA through lxml XSLT processor, all CDATA is stripped. How can I tell XSLT processor to leave CDATA as is?

PS. FYI, adding same parser to `etree.XSLT` doesn't change outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as XSLT is concerned, CDATA sections in XML are just noise. XSLT treats `<![CDATA["]]>` the same as `&quot;` which it treats the same as `"`; they are different ways for the document author to write the same thing.

If you are using CDATA sections in your input to convey information, that is if `<![CDATA[xxx]]>` means something different from `xxx`, then you need to change your XML design.

Comment: My XML is RSS, and description element contains CDATA for basic formatting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be related to lxml. It's my lack of knowledge...

CDATA in XSLT should be handled with "cdata-section-elements" attribute in output declaration. For example, if description element in XML file contains CDATA:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements='description' />
...
```